# #python While loop - The program looks like OK, but some of the tests are "runtime error" could somebody give me a hint?

Tags: python

```
sum_for_charity = int(input())
cash_payment = 0
cash_sum = 0
credit_card_payment = 0
credit_card_sum = 0
collected_sum = 0
total_sales_count = 0
buying_count = 1

command = input()

while True:
    if command != 'End':
        product_price = int(command)
        if buying_count % 2 == 0 and product_price > 100:
            credit_card_payment += 1
            collected_sum += product_price
            credit_card_sum += product_price
            print('Product sold!')
        elif buying_count % 2 == 0 and product_price <= 10:
            print('Error in transaction!')
        if buying_count % 2 != 0 and product_price <= 100:
            cash_payment += 1
            collected_sum += product_price
            cash_sum += product_price
            print('Product sold!')
        elif buying_count % 2 != 0 and product_price > 100:
            print('Error in transaction!')
        if collected_sum >= sum_for_charity:
            avr_cash = cash_sum / cash_payment
            avr_credit_card = credit_card_sum / credit_card_payment
            print(f'Average CS: {avr_cash:.2f}')
            print(f'Average CC: {avr_credit_card:.2f}')
            break
    else:
        print('Failed to collect required money for charity.')
        break
    buying_count += 1
    command = input()
```

i have a runtime error on some of the tests and i really don't see the problem. I thought that i've missed some "break" somewhere but i don't see nothing wrong. I just have to divide the cash and the credit card payments. And if the payment is correct i should print **Product sold** or if not i have to print **Error in transaction** and if i've collected all the money, i should end the loop and print the average credit card and cash buys.

Comment: Please show an example of the error.

Comment: what are the tests that cause the error?

Comment: I am sorry if my post is confusing. This is my first comment ever.
See the link   https://pastebin.com/irdUANFi
And thank you!

Comment: @QuantumMecha i am using an online judge system with total of 100 points. When i test my program in PyCharm - it works. But when i try the judge, it gives me 70/100 points and shows me two runtime errors.

Comment: You need to include the full error, and all values that you are running your code with that cause the error to occur